# Mapbox Matrix API - Avoid Motorways

Tags: mapbox, directions

The Mapbox directions API allows you to avoid motorways [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/).

Is there a way to do this in the Matrix API? It is not apparent that this is supported in the API [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/matrix-api/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Mapbox Matrix API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/#matrix) does not provide a means for avoiding motorways. The [Mapbox Directions API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/#directions) exposes an optional `exclude` parameter, documented in the table [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/#directions), which can be set to `motorway` when the `profile` parameter is either `mapbox/driving` or `mapbox/driving-traffic`. There is no `exclude` parity for the Matrix API.